# Why is calling grep using subprocess.Popen() significantly faster than using subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, time, grep, subprocess

I need to extract rows of entries in a csv-like file, and I'm using grep to do it inside a python script. I noticed that when I call grep using subprocess.check_output, it takes around 5.28 seconds to finish. But when I use subprocess.Popen, it only takes 0.002 seconds. That seems to be a massive difference and I'm wondering which one I should use. Should note that I intend to process each line as a string.

Here's part of my python script.

```
myenv = os.environ.copy()
myenv['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
file = data_path+'/'+files[12]
start = time.time()
match = 'chr3' + "[[:space:]]"
matched_reads = subprocess.Popen(['grep', match, file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=myenv)
mathced_reads = str(matched_reads).splitlines()
end = time.time()
runtime = end-start
print("Popen Grep: ", runtime)

start = time.time()
match = 'chr3' + "[[:space:]]"
matched_reads = subprocess.check_output(['grep', match, file],env=myenv)
mathced_reads = str(matched_reads).splitlines()
end = time.time()
runtime = end-start
print("Checkoutput Grep: ", runtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find that calling `Popen` does not actually execute the program and return the output, but rather it constructs a object that references the created process. In your case, you didn't call [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) which "talks" to the the process and capture its output complete.  Whereas `check_output` does all that for you. You will find that the `communicate` method will take about as long, but will actually return the desired output.

For the actual demonstration with `POpen`, replace

```
matched_reads = subprocess.Popen(['grep', match, file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=myenv)
```

with

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['grep', match, file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=myenv)
matched_reads, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Which should replicate the same behaviour as `check_output` to have `matched_reads` contain the output produced by `grep`.